# Glassfish behind Apache reverse proxy: Mod-jk or HTTP?

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, glassfish, mod-jk

I am planning a large deployment of a Glassfish-powered web application:

- A number of nodes running multiple Glassfish 3.1.1 instances are running the web application.
- The web application consists of a GoogleWebToolkit frontend and a REST gateway.
- The instances are combined behind an Apache 2.2 reverse proxy / loadbalancer.
- All client communication (mobile app, browser and other web apps) is over HTTPS, SSL is terminated at the Apache loadbalancer.

What is the benefit of running communication between Apache and Glassfish over mod-jk / AJP13 compared to HTTP in terms of performance and availability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http proxy would open many connections between your balabcer and app server. mod_jk should be less resource hungry because AJP protocol handles many requests through a single connection.

Also with mod_jk should be easier to serve static contents through the apache httpd.

btw [mod_cluster](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster) has advantages dealing with dynamically adding and removing servers but I don't see it tested with glassfish doing a quick search.

Comment: What about HTTP keep-alive?

Comment: Although ajp is binary and should be faster good http tunning may eat the difference. By default mod_proxy does not use keep-alives[1]. Recommendations are to benchmark your particular application. In my experience with mod_proxy it was easier to setup wrt ssl and cookies paths. Also client IP is visible by server. See a link list below.

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
[2] http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ajp/ajpv13a.html
[3] http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=98647
[4] http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/miscellaneous/faq.html -search for ajp

Comment: My understanding is that mod_jk can ping the downstream instances independently to detect and handle backend failures *before* a user-request comes in. Need to see how high that ranks with performance.